# Proof that the budget set is closed

Tags: microeconomics

Mas-Colell, Whinston and Green's Microeconomic Theory affirms the budget set is closed. I would like to know why.

[image]

The definition of open set in the book is the following:[image]

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking what 'closed set' means?

Answer (score 1):

Loosely speaking **closed** means that it includes the boundary. The boundary of the budget set is formed by those goods baskets ($x$) that imply spending all available income, i.e., such that $p·x=w.$ It is clear that they belong in the budget set and, hence, it is closed. (To be strict, we'd also need to check that points such as $ \vec 0$ also belong in the budget set. That's easy and I leave it for you to prove).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a set is closed if its complement is open, and if a bundle $x$ is strictly unaffordable, $p \cdot x > w$, every nearby bundle is also unaffordable.